# Setting A Cookie - Newbie

Tags: jquery, forms, cookies

I have a form for a user to submit. When they hit a submit button, I use jQuery to send off the form, but before it does it tries to retrieve the users email address that is stored in a cookie. If it can't find it, JavaScript sends off the form anyway and brings up a popup to allow the user to input their email address and this is saved to a cookie, to be retrieved next time.  I copied the code straight off w3schools because I couldn't work it out.

Right now, it doesn't work.

Please help. Here's all my code.

Thanks.

```
//#submit-form CLICK, SUBMIT FORM, BRING UP EMAIL
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit-form").click(function(){
        $("#form-wrap").addClass("fly-out-right");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#form-wrap").removeClass("animate fly-out-right");
        }, 300);
        function checkCookie(){
            username=getCookie('username');
            if (username!=null && username!=""){
                $("#submitter").val(username);
                $("#form").submit();

            } else {
                $("#email-wrap").addClass("animate");
                $("#form").submit();
                $("#submit-email").click(function(){
                    if (username!=null && username!=""){
                        username=$("#email").val();
                        setCookie('username',username,365);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});

function getCookie(c_name){
    if (document.cookie.length>0){
        c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start!=-1)
        {
            c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1;
            c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
            if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length;
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}

//SETCOOKIE FUNCTION
function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";
expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
}
```

Comment: Can you include a fiddle link with the markup? The thing with cookies is that even if it's set with jQuery/javascript it takes a reload for it to take effect.

Comment: Why not store their email server-side? Also, using w3schools is like using the Daily Mail as a reputable news source. Stop. Use the Mozilla Dev Network or similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to use a jQuery plugin - try this [easy to use & way less to code for you]
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: That could be what I need to do. I really enjoy using jQuery, but I keep getting advice to stick to pure JS. I'll give it a try.

Comment: if you really want to to this with js => download the plugin and take a look at the code. Most of it is written without the use of jQuery ;)